# How to send form text input data by bootstrap fileinput

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, field

My code:

I use bootstrap fileinput.js for upload

```
<input id="text" name="text" type="text" />
<input id="input-24" name="xls" type="file" multiple="true" multiple  lass="file-loading"/>
<script>
$("#input-24").fileinput({ 
maxFileSize: 1000000000,
maxFileCount: 1,
allowedFileExtensions: ["xls"],
uploadUrl: "<?=base_url('ajax/upxls')?>/"+     Math.round(Math.random()*56735345),
uploadAsync: true,
uploadExtraData: {
file_id : Math.round(Math.random()*56735345),
name: $("$text").val()
}

});
</script>
```

this part:

```
name: $("$text").val()
```

not change and send one default value in field.

I want send text field value by start uploading but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a jQuery selector like this

```
name: $("$text").val()
```

To get val, use id selector

```
name: $("#text").val()
```

more info on selector you can find on jQuery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)